# Select columns into an array in SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My table consists of multiple phone number columns and I want to select multiple columns (say phone numbers) into an array for my store procedure. I am trying to use `SELECT` but it returns only one value as shown in the sample code

```
DECLARE @phone VARCHAR(15)
    SELECT @phone = phone1 FROM AddressTable
PRINT @phone
```

Now I want get the values of more than one column value into one variable. I know for this purpose we normally use arrays. But I am not sure how to use. Any Help...!!!

Comment: Are you just trying to concatenate multiple columns into a single variable?  `SELECT @phone = phone1 + ', ' + phone2 ...`

Comment: @Vikram . . . What are you actually trying to accomplish?  The table format might be quite sufficient to solve your problem.

Comment: I am trying to verify the phone number format for 5 columns. I am using tsqlt. I used table format and I found its helpful. But I need to compare those results with a unique number

Comment: @Vikram . . . Why do you need all the numbers at once for verification?  Just validate one phone number at a time.

Comment: I need to test with different permutations so testing all the phone numbers columns for each test with unique phone number. which will finish off 8 tests for 5 fields.

Comment: @Vikram . . . If you need permutations, then a SQL `select` statement should be fine.  How do you get 8 tests for 5 fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL doesn't support arrays. You can use something like a table variable or a comma delimited string

[SELECT INTO a table variable in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838240/select-into-a-table-variable-in-t-sql)

Comment: You mean append all the phone numbers into a string?

Comment: I would go with the table variable, but you could go the delimited string route as well... Or xml or some other "multi" value format