# Is it possible to encapsulate sql-select result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Simple SQL query:

```
(select e.lastName as Name, count(o.orderid) as numOrd from
Employees e join Orders o on e.employeeid=o.employeeid
group by e.lastName)
```

and result

Buchanan    42
Callahan    104
Davolio     123
Dodsworth   43

My question is how to achieve in SQL something like that:

```
let queryResult = 
(select e.lastName as Name, count(o.orderid) as numOrd from
Employees e join Orders o on e.employeeid=o.employeeid
group by e.lastName)
```

and after that to write something like this, which will be the output:

```
select AVG(qr.numOrd) from queryResult qr
```

Is it possible without creating any new tables?

Comment: Sure, check table variables.

Comment: Why not just a CTE? These works well for "aliases" and allow the query planner to optimize the entire operation. Otherwise, a [SELECT INTO tv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838240/select-into-a-table-variable-in-t-sql) can be used if the results need to be forced, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, but why not just something like:

```
select count(o.orderid) / count (distinct e.employeeid) AvgNumOrder
  from orders
```

Derived tables, CTEs, Subqueries, Temp tables, tables variable all do what you ask, but none are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [SQL Server Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

You can define view as

```
create view queryResult as
select e.lastName as Name, count(o.orderid) as numOrd from
Employees e join Orders o on e.employeeid=o.employeeid
group by e.lastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [a Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).