# how to assign query result to local variable in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

I need to stored/ assign query result of multiple columns to local variable

for example;

```
declare @localVariable

select @localVariable = userId, userName, email, address 
from user;
```

I believe the above code is not correct!

Comment: There might be more than one row on `userId` column in `user` table, which row value did you want to store?

Comment: Declare your [variable as table](https://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx) and insert your results into it...

Comment: `FROM user` won't work, `USER` is a reserved word in T-SQL. You would need to quote your object name (or better yet, rename your object to a name that isn't a reserved word).

Comment: What exactly do you want to capture? Entire row? Entire table? Nth column from result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT INTO a table variable in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838240/select-into-a-table-variable-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare a table variable for that:

```
DECLARE @localVariable AS TABLE
(
    userId int,
    userName varchar(10),
    email nvarchar(100),
    address nvarchar(1000)
);

INSERT INTO @localVariable (userId, userName, email, address)
SELECT userId, userName, email, address
FROM [user];
```

Comment: You need to quote the object name. This won't compile as is.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix variable assignment and data-retrieval inside a select statement. This will not work:

```
DECLARE @localVariable INT;
SELECT TOP 1 @localVariable = userId, userName FROM user;
```

But this will:

```
-- copy values from multiple columns to variables
DECLARE @localVariable1 INT;
DECLARE @localVariable2 VARCHAR(100);
SELECT TOP 1 @localVariable1 = userId, @localVariable2 = userName FROM user;
```

Comment: `USER` is a reserved word.